# How to recover a broken WordPress without a backup?

Tags: wordpress, restore, google-cloud-platform

I have Wordpress installed. I removed a few lines of code in a Category PHP file. When I clicked saved I lost access my domain. When I attempted to access my domain my browser is a blank white. I'm not able to access anything relating to Wordpress admin, login or etc.

I'm new to Google Cloud. I did not setup or schedule a backup before the loss. Is there a way I can restore my domain to the point before the crash?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've damaged your database - just that your app is in a broken state and cannot be run until it is repaired. Can you take a backup of your files and database now? That would be a good start. Also, there's a lesson to learn here: don't edit your live site, always work on an offline copy.

Comment: What is a "Category PHP file"? Do you mean a "category.php" in your current theme? That should not break everything - maybe try clearing your browser cookies and try logging onto the home page again?

Comment: I suspect that you have a PHP error in `category.php` which is not being displayed by the server, as it's unlikey `category.php` would fobar your whole site.  Which theme are you using?  If it's one of the default ones, try pasting a fresh copy over it.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the database and started from scratch. I know going forward to make all changing in a test database first.